# How to get a sum for a particular attribute in a CoreData DB?

Tags: ios, core-data, nsfetchrequest, nsentitydescription

I recently have just been able to populate my core data DB.  I have an attribute named *username* and I would like to get the total number of users on the system (in the DB) and print it out.  I know I need to use *NSFetchRequest* along with *NSEntityDescription*.  I am just not sure how to go about it.  I haven't really seen a question like this on SO.  The entity is named *Account* and my attribute is labeled *username*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your particular case, I suppose you have each *username* as a separate record so you can use the `-countForFetchRequest:error:` method of `NSManagedObjectContext` to get the number of objects a given fetch request would have returned if it had been passed to `executeFetchRequest:error:`

Comment: you mean do something like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1611342/coredata-countforfetchrequest-says-entity-not-found

Comment: got it working, i guess i'll give you the answer would have like to seen some written out code ... oh well.